# "unused arguments" error in toGeoJSON function in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to run this basic example of using leafletR package (which is taken from the leafletR package documentation):

```
# load example data (Fiji Earthquakes)
data(quakes)

# store data in GeoJSON file (just a subset here)
q.dat <- toGeoJSON(data=quakes[1:99,], dest=tempdir(), name="quakes")
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in toGeoJSON(data = quakes[1:99, ], dest = tempdir(), name = "quakes") : 
  unused arguments (data = quakes[1:99, ], dest = tempdir(), name = "quakes")
```

this is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.1      rMaps_0.1.1     rCharts_0.4.2   base64enc_0.1-2 RCurl_1.95-4.1  bitops_1.0-6    whisker_0.3-2  
 [8] RJSONIO_1.2-0.2 yaml_2.1.13     leafletR_0.2-1  maps_2.3-7      shiny_0.10.0    devtools_1.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] caTools_1.17       digest_0.6.4       evaluate_0.5.1     grid_3.0.2         htmltools_0.2.4    httpuv_1.3.0      
 [7] httr_0.3           lattice_0.20-23    memoise_0.2.1      parallel_3.0.2     RColorBrewer_1.0-5 Rcpp_0.11.2       
[13] stringr_0.6.2      tools_3.0.2        xtable_1.7-3      
> args(leafletR::toGeoJSON)
function (data, name, dest, lat.lon, overwrite = TRUE) 
NULL
```

could someone explain to me where is my mistake?

thanks

Comment: Please post your `sessionInfo()`, it works for me.

Comment: It would also help if you posted `args(leafletR::toGeoJSON)`

Comment: I added the extra info to the post, thanks.

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created another object with the name `toGeoJSON`, try `leafletR::toGeoJSON(data=quakes[1:99,], dest=tempdir(), name="quakes")`. If that works, then `rm(toGeoJSON)` should get rid of the fake one.